# Retrieve distance from visible part of Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, distance

I want to draw a static circle over a map with `Google Maps`. When the user pinches, the map will zoom in/out.

I need to know the map radius (related to the area contained in the circle) and change the seekbar at the bottom accordingly.

Does anybody know a solution how to retrieve the distance from the left to the right screen edge? I didn't find anything at the [Google Maps API doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/).

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

using VisibleRegion you can get the all corner cordinates and also the center.

```
VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
```

and you can calcuate distance from two region by this

```
Location MiddleLeftCornerLocation;//(center's latitude,vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude)
Location center=new Location("center");
center.setLatitude( vr.latLngBounds.getCenter().latitude);
center.setLongitude( vr.latLngBounds.getCenter().longitude);
float dis = center.distanceTo(MiddleLeftCornerLocation);//calculate distane between middleLeftcorner and center
```

[image]

Comment: getting the distance from the top corner is going to make the circle bigger than the visible area width wise so this isnt really correct

Comment: Actually i meant middle left corner. I have now corrected my answer

Comment: how to calculate MiddleLeftCornerLocation? it's null

Comment: tyczj, you can calculate distanse to top and distanse to left and choice smaller.

Comment: If you zoom out enough the circle wont be in the middle of visible view and the radius would also become smaller than half of the width/height, can you explain it?

Answer (score 13):

I got a while to write the code for "MiddleLeftCornerLocation" variable in the great answer given by @Md. Monsur Hossain Tonmoy, so just to complete it (I haven't enough reputation points to comment your answer, sorry):

```
    VisibleRegion vr = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;

    Location center = new Location("center");
    center.setLatitude(vr.latLngBounds.getCenter().latitude);
    center.setLongitude(vr.latLngBounds.getCenter().longitude);

    Location middleLeftCornerLocation = new Location("center");
    middleLeftCornerLocation.setLatitude(center.getLatitude());
    middleLeftCornerLocation.setLongitude(left);

    float dis = center.distanceTo(middleLeftCornerLocation);
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the map center point with

```
googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

then figure out the width of the map and get the height/2 and convert them to a `Point` using  the `x` `y` values you just got.

then relate that point to the map

```
LatLng widthPoint = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(point);
```

now that you have the tagret point and the width point you can calculate the distance between the 2 points which will give you the radius.

**Note**

this assumes always in portrait mode, if you are in landscape mode the circle will be bigger than the visible area so in this case you will want to get the distance from the height